# import python package from a different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I've run into an import issue in my library, when trying to replicate the notebooks behavior in [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). In this case, a Juypter Notebook in the notebooks directory includes `import shap`, where the shap package includes all of the functionality.

My library has a similar structure, where I have `import package`. This package has an `__init__.py` file, but the following error occurs

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

The fix is likely trivial, but I have not been able to work it out.

File structure:

```
dir  
 |  
 +--notebooks  
 |      |  
 |      +--foo.ipynb  
 |  
 +--package  
        |  
        +--__init__.py  
        |  
        +--subpackage1  
        |  
        +--subpackage2
```

Both subpackage1 and subpackage2 have an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Can you describe your folder structure (where files are located): the script you want to execute and the package

Comment: Personnally, I use `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))` in my `init.my` files to solve this kind of issue.